# RoR + Redis Master - Slaves

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, high-availability

im hacking an app using RoR and Redis.

The Redis infrastructure wil have one master ( Writer ) and 3 slaves ( Readers ) and using HAProxy as load balancer to the Slaves.

What approach , you guys, are using in this scenario?

Should I have two Redis Client , one to MASTER and other to SLAVE (load balancer) ?

what is the best approach ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a wrapper on top of the redis connection. This way you can transparently implement the logic for implement writer/reader and use any scenario you want (this could be environment specific).

This way you can either call it direcly

```
RedisWrapper.hget(key, field)
```

or build a layer on top of it (think something like `remodel`).

Comment: Thanks for answer Radim. Yeah, I´am considering use this approach. When a write message ( Save, Update, Delete) come to RedisWrapper I´ll use the the connection if the redis writer node otherwise read messages will connect with the load balancer.
Makes sense ?

Comment: Absolutely and its easier to test/mock it.